multiplying a constant value in a dicom RT Dose
I am beginner in Python. I have exported the RT Dose file from treatment planning system and I want to multiply its voxel values in a constant value (int or float). I have written the following code to do this multiplication. This code multiplies the dose values well for int numbers. Can you help me how can I modify this code for float numbers so that I can multiply the integers and floats to get the correct result? (i.e, multiply the dose values in 3, 2.8 , etc?)
import os
import pydicom

#directory path
directory_path = r'D:\RT Dose'

for filename in os.listdir(directory_path):
    if filename.endswith(".dcm"):
        file_path = os.path.join(directory_path, filename)
        rt_dose = pydicom.dcmread(file_path)

       #pixel array
        dose_data = rt_dose.pixel_array

       #multiplying
        constant_value = 3
        modified_dose_data = dose_data * constant_value

        rt_dose.PixelData = modified_dose_data.tobytes()

        # save
        output_file_path = os.path.join(directory_path, f"modified_{filename}")
        rt_dose.save_as(output_file_path)

    print(f"Modified file saved as: {output_file_path}")


Easiest way should be to leave the Pixel Data untouched and instead use DoseGridScaling:
rt_dose.DoseGridScaling *= constant_value

DICOM readers should respect the scaling value.
